# How to obtain a partial wake lock for an inline broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

I have a receiver , that would receive a broadcast in future from an intentservice . 
I have initialized the receiver inside my activity .

Sometimes the IntentService takes a while to complete, so by the time it broadcasts its result , the cellphone device is sleeping , so the broadcast is not received.

I have confirmed that even if the cellphone is sleeping , the IntentService runs to completion , only the broadcast receiver doesn't receive anything .

I know that I have to obtain a partial wake lock somehow and somewhere :( . I am in the dark about this .

This is my simple activity , with the only the relevant parts only .

```
public class NewsActivity extends Activity implements OnDownloadComplete{

...
..
..



 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {


     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          ..
          System.out.println("Called"); // Not printed on logcat if the cell is sleeping


        }
      };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);


    ..
    ..

    ..

    /*LAUNCHING SERVICE*/
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsSyncTask.class);
    intent.putExtra( NewsSyncTask.NOTIFICATION, Footer.this.receiverNotificationClass);
    context.startService(intent);





}
```

}

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceiver should receive broadcast, you can try in this way first wright a separate class and extend it with BroadcastReceiver declare your BroadcastReceiver in menifest.xml under reciver tag, you should set intent filter to it so that it should listen only the broadcast which your intent service dose.

Use AlarmManager with a _WAKEUP-style alarm. Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/) illustrating its use (along with a WakefulIntentService you will want, to make sure the device does not fall back asleep during your network I/O).

Comment: you suggest externalizing the declaration of the receiver in the manifest should solve this issue ? . 

I am not still sure if I need to launch a WakefulIntentService , as I said I can see that the IS runs to completion with the cellphone sleeping . But you still think I should look into this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

MainActivity:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    //Start the Service

    wl.release();
```